# create dummy records with image upload for dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, carrierwave

I want to create users and a bunch of their images in a rake task.

```
10.times do
  user = User.create :username => Faker::Name.name,
              :email => Faker::Internet.email,
              :password => "password",
              :password_confirmation => "password"

    10.times do
      Image.create :user_id => user.id,
                   :name => Faker::Name.name,
                   :image => "../assets/musk_ox.jpg" # feeble attempt clearly doesn't work
    end

end
```

How can I fake this? The images don't have to be unique but it would great if they were. It would also be great if each user had 5-10 images randomly.

I'm using carrierwave and mini_magick.

Here's the form that a real user would use just for reference.

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <% if @image.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Add Image", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
10.times do
      user = User.create :username => Faker::Name.name,
                         :email => Faker::Internet.email,
                         :password => "password",
                         :password_confirmation => "password"

      rand(5...10).times do |i|
        Image.create :user_id => user.id,
                     :name => Faker::Name.name,
                     # I get a rnd number between 5 & 10 above then just plug that index 
                     # and path into the File class' join method
                     :image => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/lib/assets/#{i}.jpg"))
```